# overriding bundler's release, but without putting it in the gem

Tags: ruby, bundler, geminabox

I'm using bundler to manage my gem's dependencies, and I'm using geminabox to host my gems once they're ready. Using bundler's `rake release` is bad news, because my gems will go to rubygems, not to geminabox, however the additional functionality (push a tag etc) from that task are really helpful.

I wrote a gem which adds the ability to `rake release geminabox` and `rake release rubygems`, but now my library (which has nothing to do with geminabox) depends on this bundler/geminabox thing, which in turn depends on geminabox, and futher on sinatra, rack... all of a sudden my development requirements are huge and are only specific to *my* development situation. Some of these gems will be released publicly and these geminabox development dependencies will not be necessary to anyone else.

I realise that injecting a gem into a bundler gemset is specifically what bundler is intended to prevent, so what would you recommend as a way to have my own custom release functionality which is not tied to the gem itself?

Answer (score 0):

I've redefined the default Bundler release task in my gem's Rakefiles along the lines below. You're right that you don't want to suck in Sinatra and a whole bloated stack.

You are left with 2 choices...

1. write custom rake tasks that do everything you need from scratch
2. redefine Bundler's default release task, since that's the only bit you want to behave differently.

Rakefile

```
require "bundler/gem_tasks"

Rake::TaskManager.class_eval do
  def remove_task(task_name)
    @tasks.delete(task_name.to_s)
  end
end
def remove_task(task_name)
  Rake.application.remove_task(task_name)
end

remove_task :release # So we don't publish to rubygems.org
desc "release to geminabox"
task :release => [:build] do |t|
  system "gem inabox"
end
```